# RevolutionPlot3D around y-axis

Tags: plotting

I'm to rotate the region bounded by $x=y-y^2$ and $x=0$ about the $y$-axis. I was successful with this:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{y - y^2, y}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

Which rotated about the z-axis.

[image]

But I'd like to use RevolutionPlot3D with RevolutionAxis->{0,1,0} and have been unsuccessful thus far. Any thoughts?

And, yes I was successful with ParametricPlot3D, but I am trying to get a better understanding of RevolutionPlot3D and see if it is useful for my students.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get what you want by telling `RevolutionPlot3D` that the plane curve lies in the yz-plane. To do that, you must give the curve in 3D parametric form. Like so:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{0, t, t - t^2}, {t, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z},
 RevolutionAxis -> {0, 1, 0}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for the help. Now I'll practice using your suggestion.